# React error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of null after

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-scripts

I recently upgraded to node v12.10.0 and a project that was working fine began to have several issues with dependencies which were resolved by removing the dependencies with the issues, removing package-lock.json and node_modules folder and running npm install.  However, I am now faced a 'concat' error and am not sure where the culprit could be.

Here is the error screen:

[image]

here are the dependencies list:

```
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"classnames": "^2.2.5",
"connected-react-router": "^6.9.1",
"emotion": "^7.3.2",
"history": "^4.10.1",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"lodash.flatten": "^4.4.0",
"lodash.flow": "^3.5.0",
"lodash.orderby": "^4.6.0",
"mapbox-gl": "^2.1.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"prettier": "1.7.2",
"primeicons": "^2.0.0",
"primereact": "^3.4.0",
"prop-types": "^15.5.10",
"query-string": "^6.11.0",
"react": "^16.4.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
"react-calendar": "^2.17.5",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-fa": "^5.0.0",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^4.0.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.2",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-redux": "next",
"react-scripts": "1.0.11",
"react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-auth-wrapper": "^2.0.2",
"redux-form": "^8.3.7",
"redux-persist": "^4.10.1",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"turf-feature": "^1.0.0"
```

It seems to be connected to webpack though I am not referencing webpack directly.  It seems as if one of the dependencies might be using webpack and that dependency is the culprit.

Update: ran the command `npm ci` using the original package-lock.json and package.json files and am receiving the following error:

```
./node_modules/mapbox-gl/src/shaders/index.js
Module parse failed: …/node_modules/mapbox-gl/src/shaders/index.js Unexpected token (10:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const fs = require('fs');
| 
| const shaders: {[string]: {fragmentSource: string, vertexSource: string}} = {
|     prelude: {
|         fragmentSource: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../shaders/_prelude.fragment.glsl', 'utf8'),
```

Comment: `react-scripts` 1.0.11 is 4 years old now, a year older than the initial react 16 release. It manages ALL of the webpack,babel,loaders,css, etc. You definitely want to get that up to `^3.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

Of what I got from the information provided, it is a version issue related to *bootstrap* package.

Run `npm ci` to install packages by the working versions for your project - this command reads info from `package-lock.json`.

P.S. If the package-lock is already deleted, then you can find it in your recycle bin, restore it and reinstall the working versions of the packages used.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it did get me past the error bit now I am receiving the new error listed above in the body.